# How to create a SQL Compact 3.5 database for Windows Mobile in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

In an ASP.NET web application I have to dynamically create a **SQL Compact 3.5 database** for a Windows Mobile Compact Framework application from a data source (SQL Server).

I have to create the database file, needed objects (tables, ...) and fill the tables with data. The client application (Windows Mobile device ) will download that generated file.

What prerequisites (referenced assemblies, installations) do I need - or: is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially Henk's answer points in the right direction. But there are some caveats. The SQLServerCE assembly throws runtime errors.

I found these two helpful links:

- [SQL Server Compact Edition under ASP.net and IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2006/11/27/sql-server-compact-edition-under-asp-net-and-iis.aspx) (Steve Lasker's blog)
- [Using SQL Compact Edition Under ASP.NET](http://www.zorched.net/2007/01/17/using-sql-compact-edition-under-aspnet/) by Geoff Lane

In order to use the assembly, you have to call this method:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerEverywhereUnderWebHosting", true)
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need at least the System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly. That is normally in the GAC but it might be usable as a locally copied DLL.

From there on you can instantiate a SqlCeEngine object and use CreateDatabase()

Here is some  [CodeProject example code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/DBApplicationsForPocketPC.aspx) in VB.NET.

Answer (score -1):

You need the SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 Runtime:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DC614AEE-7E1C-4881-9C32-3A6CE53384D9&displaylang=en

Then add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe

Here is some sample code that creates a new database:

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

public static class SqlCompactServices
{
    public static void CreateDatabase()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=file.sdf";
        using (SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString))
        {
            engine.CreateDatabase();
        }

        using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            // preform queries just like "regular" SQL Server
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you even bother to read splattne's answer?  THe point is that you have to call a special method to get it to work.

Comment: Does what he put actually work?  It isn't called SQL Server Everywhere any more.